# How to Update jdl file and add relationship for @CollectionTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jhipster

Let say i already have customer table and created a new phone table and below java code i have update for Phone collection table mapping. In this case what are the changes i need to do in JDL file for @CollectionTable

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;
  private String name;
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "PHONES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"CUST_ID"))
  @Column(name = "PH_NO")
  private List<String> phoneNumbers;
    .............
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the code in the question?

Comment: JDL does not support this, you have to customize generated code manually as you already did.